# Passing list as a function parameter and returning list from a function

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I have the following code:

```
(defun read_coords (in)
    (setq x (read-line))
    (if (equalp x "0")
        in
        (progn
            (append in (cons x nil))
            (read_coords in)
        )
    )
)

(setq coords (read_coords (cons nil nil)))
```

The goal is to read lines of input and store them in a list. The problem is that the list `coords` remains unchanged (thus containing only `NIL`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please fix indentation and paren placing.

Comment: sorry about that, is it better now?

Comment: moderately. :-(  Please use Emacs - it will indent your code correctly, and avoid hanging parens.

Comment: ok, I will try it; I've had no idea of a LISP editor so I am using regular notepad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` does not modify its arguments, i.e., since you are not using its value, you are not doing anything.

```
(defun read-coords (&optional accumulation)
  (let ((x (read-line)))
    (if (string= x "0")
        (nreverse accumulation) ; done
        (read-coords (cons x accumulation)))))
(defvar *coords* (read-coords))
```

Comment: Better put the `nreverse` call inside the function.

Answer (score 5):

Here is your code, with better formatting:

```
(defun read_coords (in)
  (setq x (read-line))
  (if (equalp x "0")
      in
      (progn
        (append in (cons x nil))
        (read_coords in))))

(setq coords (read_coords (cons nil nil)))
```

Now, what is the return value of `read_coords`? A function contains an implicit [`PROGN`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/s_progn.htm), hence it is the last form. Here, the last form is an [`IF`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm). Depending on the outcome of the test, the return value is either `in` or the return value of `PROGN` in *else* position. Thus, the return value in case the test fails is the one obtained by calling `(read_coords in)`. When the recursion eventually ends without error, it is necessarily in the *then* branch of the `IF`, which returns `in`. *Note that `in` is never modified during the whole execution*.

Indeed, [`APPEND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_append.htm) creates a fresh list based on its inputs. In other words, the new list is the value returned by the call to `APPEND`, which unfortunately is never stored anywhere. The computation is done without any side-effect and its result is discarded.
You should probably do this instead:

```
(read_coords (append in (cons x nil)))
```

Thus, the new list is being passed as an argument to the recursive call.

### Remarks

```
(setq x (read-line))
```

Don't use [`SETQ`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/s_setq.htm) to define local variables. You need to use a [`LET`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm)-binding here. Otherwise you change the global lexical scope in a way that is implementation-dependent (except if you defined a global variable named `x`, which is bad because it goes against the naming convention of special variables, which should have `*earmuffs*`). Mutating a global variable inside a function makes it possibly non-reentrant, which is pretty bad.

```
(cons x nil)
```

In order to build a list with one element, just use [`LIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/a_list.htm):

```
(list x)
```

Finally, note that you shoudn't use underscores in names, prefer dashes. Hence, your function should be named `read-coords`, or better yet, `read-coordinates`.

```
(equalp x "0")
```

Even though the above is correct, it might be better to use `string=` here, since you know [`READ-LINE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_lin.htm) returns a string.

### Performance

You are appending a list again and again, which makes a copy for each element being read. Your code is being quadratic in time and space usage, for a task that can done with a linear algorithm.
Moreover, you are using a tail-recursive function where a simple iteration would be clearer and more idiomatic. We generally don't use tail-recursive procedures in Common Lisp because the language provides iteration control structure and because tail-merging optimization is not guaranteed to be always applied (the optimization being not mandatory (which is a good thing) does not prevent implementations to provide it, even though it might require additional declarations from the user). Better use a [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) here:

```
(defun read-coordinates (&optional (input-stream *standard-input*))
  (loop for line = (read-line input-stream nil nil)
        until (or (not line) (string= line "0"))
        collect line))
```

We pass an input stream in parameter, which defaults to [`*STANDARD-INPUT*`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/v_debug_.htm). Then `READ-LINE` reads lines while ignoring errors (thanks to the first NIL). In case an error is found, like when we reach end-of-file, the returned value is NIL (thanks to the second NIL). The `LOOP` ends when the line being read is either NIL or equal to `"0"`. The loop accumulates all the successive lines being read into a list.

Comment: Wow, such a great explanation! I am a LISP beginner and I really appreciate your effort :)

Comment: @karlosss Thanks a lot.